# How do I reference in header files?

Tags: c++, reference, header-files

I'm working on a library but lately, I get error messages.
My references are not recognized, I can't find the problem everything should be oke. I'm missing something and I need some help.

Here is the code:

header file :

```
#ifndef DEMONIC_H
#define DEMONIC_H

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<utility>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>


// Conversions
    std::vector<std::string> strtovec(std::string to_vec);
    std::string bashtostr(std::string command);
    std::vector<std::string> bashtovec(std::string command);

// Booleans
    bool charinstr(char input_char, std::string str);
    bool strinstr(std::string &sub_str, std::string &full_str);

// Colors & highlights
    std::string clrstr(std::string to_color, std::string color);
    std::string highlight_instr(std::string str, std::string to_highlight);

// Math
    int true_rand(int range_min, int range_max);
    double linear_interpl(double val, double min, double max);

#endif //DEMONIC_H
```

source file:

```
#include "demonic.h"

// Conversions
std::vector<std::string> strtovec (std::string to_vec) {
    int pos = 0, len = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    // Iterate through the string
    for (int i = 0; i < to_vec.length(); i++){
        char c = to_vec[i];

        // Splitting points
        if (c == 32 || c == 10){
            vec.push_back(to_vec.substr(pos, len));
            len = 0;
            pos = i+1;
        }else if (i == to_vec.length()-1){
            int end = to_vec.length() - pos;
            vec.push_back(to_vec.substr(pos, end));
        }
        else{
            len++;
        }

    }
    return vec;
}
bool charinstr(char input_char, std::string str){
    for (char c : str){
        if (input_char == c){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
std::string bashtostr(std::string command) {
    std::string data;
    FILE *stream;
    const int maxBuffer = 256;
    char buffer[maxBuffer];
    command.append(" 2>&1");

    stream = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
    if (stream) {
        while (!feof(stream))
            if (fgets(buffer, maxBuffer, stream) != nullptr)
                data.append(buffer);
        pclose(stream);
    }
    return data;
}
std::vector<std::string> bashtovec(std::string command){
    return strtovec(command);
}

// Booleans
bool strinvec(std::string str, std::vector<std::string> vec){
    for (std::string vec_str : vec){
        return strinstr(str, vec_str);
    }
    return false;
}
bool strinstr(std::string &sub_str, std::string &full_str){
    size_t sub_len = sub_str.length(), full_len = full_str.length();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < full_len; i++){
        if (sub_str != "" && (i + sub_len) < full_len && full_str.substr(i, sub_len) == sub_str) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Colors & highlights
std::string clrstr(std::string to_color, const char color) {
    std::string reset = "\u001b[0m";

    // Turn upper chars to lower, so it doesnt matter what chase is used.
    for (char c : color){
        c = tolower(c);
    }

    // Change color to black
    if (color == "black") {
        std::string black = "\u001b[30m";
        return black + to_color + reset;
    }
        // Change color to red
    else if (color == "red") {
        std::string red = "\u001b[31m";
        return red + to_color + reset;
    }
        // Change color to green
    else if (color == "green") {
        std::string green = "\u001b[32m";
        return green + to_color + reset;
    }
        // Change color to yellow
    else if (color == "yellow") {
        std::string yellow = "\u001b[33m";
        result = yellow + to_color + reset;
    }
        // Change color to magenta/purple
    else if (color == "magenta" || color == "purple") {
        std::string purple = "\u001b[35m";
        return purple + to_color + reset;
    }
        // Change color to white
    else if (color == "white") {
        std::string white = "\u001b[37m";
        return white + to_color + reset;
    }

}
std::string highlight_instr(std::string str, std::string to_highlight){

    std::string result;

    // Makes the text-color green
    std::string green = "\u001b[32m";
    // Puts the color back the way it was
    std::string reset = "\u001b[0m";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length();){
        // If a match is encountered the color will be installed
        if (str.substr(i, to_highlight.length()) == to_highlight){
            result.append(green);
            result.append(to_highlight);
            result.append(reset);
            i = i + to_highlight.length();

            // Otherwise a letter is just added
        }else{
            result.push_back(str[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Math
int true_rand(int range_min, int range_max){
    srand(time(0));
    int r = rand() % range_max;
    while (r < range_min){
        r = rand() % range_max;
        }
    return r;
}
double linear_interpl(double val, double min, double max) {

    // Lowering the minimal to 0 and subtract it from the other values
    double new_max = (max - min);
    double new_val = (val - min);

    // The sum
    return (new_val / new_max * 100);
}
```

Please point out to me what the deal is so I can use the actual code. I worked with it for months and there was never a problem, something happened it seems while I was working on it.

Comment: _"but lately, I get error messages."_ - please post those error messages (as text). _"My references are not recognized"_ - What does this mean, you get an undefined reference error?

Comment: Something that you have declared and are using does not have a definition. Compare the prototypes of your declarations and definitions carefully. (There is one problem that causes a compilation error. Start there.)

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. Presumably, `if (c == 32 || c == 10)` is supposed to be checking for whitespace. Write that as `if (c == ' ' || c == '\n')` or, better, `if (std::isspace(c))`. Even simpler: `std::ostrstream text(to_vec); std::string word; while (text >> word) vec.push_back(word);`.

Comment: And while I'm giving coding advice, don't reinvent the wheel. `charinstr` is just `str.find(input_char) != str.end()`. `strinstr` is (I think; it's hard to read) just `full_str.find(sub_str) != full_str.end()`. And in `true_rand`, only call `srand(time(0))` **once**, at the start of the program. And it can be written much more simply: `return rand() % (range_max - range_min + 1) + range_min;`.

Answer (score 1):

in header: `std::string clrstr(std::string to_color, std::string color);`, in source: `std::string clrstr(std::string to_color, const char color)` => mismatch.

And then there's a `result = yellow + to_color + reset;` which should instead be a `return`.

But the important lesson here is not the *errors*, it's the lack of a *version-control system*. Do yourself a favor and use [git](https://git-scm.com/) for maintaining changes to your project. Commit and push a *working* copy (one that compiles) and add changes incrementally with a message. When something is not working, you can check which changes happened since last time and find the error, or just revert it.